# SailsJS clickJacking is working for api calls and redirects but when using curl command it does not show X-Frame-options in return details

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sails.js, clickjacking

I have angular/Node/Sails setup and when I call the site it always redirects to a default state and all the calls in network have `X-Frame-Options` turned on and displayed in the calls but when I am trying to use comand `curl -v https://{SiteURL}/` in the command details it does not list `X-Frame-Option` at all.
Also, If I use `curl -v https://{SiteURL}/{DefaultState}` it has `X-Frame-Options` header defines in the detail it returns.

I am using the clickJacking solution mentions on sailsJS document link mentions below.
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/clickjacking

I was expecting it would work out of the box by anyway we test it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.